# How to create column blocks by bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

My question is how to create this with bootstrap ,
one column at the middle and two columns with two rows at right and left like below picture: 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid" style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- First Section -->
      <div class="col">
        <div class="row">
          <div style="background-color: red;" class="col-12">1</div>
          <div style="background-color: green;" class="col">
            2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Second section -->
      <div class="col" style="background-color: pink;">3
      </div>

      <!-- Third Section -->
      <div class="col">
        <div class="row">
          <div style="background-color: red;" class="col-12">1</div>
          <div style="background-color: green;" class="col">
            2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```